# Print quantity from XML sheet into asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, xpath, xmldocument

I have tried to get this to work however have had minimal success, I've tried to use a few examples however none are exactly as I require, Simply put, I know what I have to do, I just don't understand how to do it.

I am attempting to get quantities larger than 10 from an xml sheet, I am then trying to print how many of them exist.

Example of XML File:

```
<PurchaseCollection xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<purchases>
<Purchase>
  <id>1</id>
  <fullName>Annet Stevens</fullName>
  <emailAddress>annet@stevens.com</emailAddress>
  <productname>Sandal wood</productname>
  <unitprice>500</unitprice>
  <quantity>11</quantity>
</Purchase>
<Purchase>
  <id>2</id>
  <fullName>Bert Waywood</fullName>
  <emailAddress>bert@waywood.com</emailAddress>
  <productname>Sandal Leaf</productname>
  <unitprice>17</unitprice>
  <quantity>25</quantity>
</Purchase>
</purchases>
</PurchaseCollection>
```

Example of ASP.Net Back end Code being used.

```
    //Attempt to count quantity greater than 10.
    const string FILENAME1 = "GoodXML.xml";
    String file1 = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, FILENAME);

    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load(file1);

    XmlNode quantity = doc.SelectSingleNode("/PurchaseCollection/purchases/Purchase/[quantity>10]");
    string comments = quantity.InnerText;

    //Req (using System.Xml;)

    Label1.Text = comments (Total amount of quantity here.);
```

I am using a grid view table with binding which may be causing issues, but as it is within a separate section I do not believe this to be a case.

Front End Code Example:

```
<p><asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="" ></asp:Label></p>
```

At the moment I am being met with 'Expression must evaluate to node error' which I understand is due to it being unable to find the node of 'quantity'.

I believe I am about 80% of the way there, I was hoping someone more experienced may offer insight.
Please do not over engineer the solution, the simpler the example the better ideally

Comment: I'm far from being an xpath expert but it seems to me that `quantity>10` could in theory return multiple nodes matching the criteria. In your example there's only one, but I would assume it returns a node set (containing 1 item) rather than a single node directly. I don't know that for sure but it seems possibly / likely. Something for you to investigate.

Comment: `At the moment I am being met with 'Expression must evaluate to node error' which I understand is due to it being unable to find the node of 'quantity'.` So... why is it unable to find that node? Is it perhaps because your XPath expression is incorrect?

Comment: @IanKemp, I'm fairly certain it is incorrect, I'm just uncertain 'how' to make it correct e.g. square brackets [ ] or use the ( ), I have withdrawn some values for simplicity sake, there are about 10 purchase ID's, I want to get all the values of those 10 with a quantity higher than 10. then have as an example. 

Label1.Text will print "There are 4 examples of quantity being higher than 10." 

I will continue to try, thankyou for zoning in on the area, I hope someone can provide more insight.

Comment: So if you're _expecting_ multiple results, then start by trying with SelectNodes then, instead of SelectSingleNode. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlnode.selectnodes?view=net-5.0

Comment: And also try amending the xpath to `/PurchaseCollection/purchases/Purchase[quantity > 10]`

Answer (score 2):

It is better to use LINQ to XML API. It is available in the .Net Framework since 2007.

**c#**

```
void Main()
{
    const string FILENAME = @"e:\temp\GoodXML.xml";
    XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
    
    int counter = xdoc.Descendants("quantity")
        .Where(x => Convert.ToInt32(x.Value) > 10)
        .Count();
    
    Console.WriteLine("Counter: {0}", counter);
}
```